# ElectronJs y Electron-packager, ejecucion global

Tags: electron, packages, aplicación-escritorio, electron-build

Soy programador web, y estoy aprendiendo a usar electronjs para realizar aplicaciones de escritorio usando los conocimientos previos de la web.

Tengo una duda al momento de realizar la compilación, e instalado electronjs y electron-packager de manera global. Esto es debido a la poca velocidad de Internet que tengo, para evitar retrasos en tener que esperar a que se descarguen los paquetes.

Al momento de realizar el build con electron-packager me indica que no encuentra la carpeta electron dentro de node_module, se que con instalar electronjs de manera local en el proyecto ya se soluciona, pero es justo lo que no quiero hacer.

¿Existe una manera de apuntar hacia la instalación del paquete electron que instale de manera global y asi pueda realizar el build, o alguna recomendación que puedan darme?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿cómo tienes las dependencias puestas en package.json?

Comment: Lo tengo de esta manera.

"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^9.2.0"
},
"dependencies": {}

Answer (score 1):

He estado buscando información por varios sitios y parece que no se puede hacer que el fichero `package.json` de un proyecto use como dependencias un módulo instalado como global.
Entiendo tu problema y es un caso particular, pero este tipo de herramientas intentan evitar lo que se consideran malas prácticas: se espera que cualquiera que se baje un proyecto de un repositorio de versiones pueda ejecutar "npm install" y obtener en la carpeta `node_modules` local todo lo que necesita para ejecutar su código.

Una opción que puedes intentar es copiar manualmente las dependencias desde tu carpeta global a tu proyecto local, de ese modo npm seguramente se salte la descarga porque detectará que esa dependencia está ya presente. Otra opción es crear un enlace (un "soft link" en sistemas Linux) para no ocupar espacio extra en el disco.